# How to test extra dimensions?

Tags: experimental-physics, spacetime, string-theory, compactification

It is predicted in string theory that our world has some extra dimensions. I'm wondering if we want to prove this experimentally, what should we do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One proposed test is measuring the strength of gravity.

Gravity has the property that if there are $n$ dimensions of space, the strength of gravity when distance increases diminishes by $$\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}$$
In our current understanding of the universe, there are 3 spatial dimensions, therefore the strength of gravity reduces in accordance with the well-known factor $$\frac{1}{r^2}$$
But, if in case in large scale measurements we measure that factor to actually be, say for example, $$\frac{1}{r^3}$$then we can deduce that there are $3 + 1 = 4$ spatial dimensions.
Note that in this experiment we have to reasonably large distances for measurements.

Comment: The extra dimensions of string theory are compactified. Why would they affect gravity only at very large scales? M theory allows something more like it, but again, why the effect only on the very large?